# Getting all the Google Ads Labels from MCC. Also the onces created by other users within a client account

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google Ad Scripts makes it possible to get the labels of child/client accounts. But not the onces, who are created by a client itself. Is there a way to get ALL the labelnames?

I tried serveral script, but all are returning the MCC labels

```
function getAllAccountLabels() {
  var labelIterator = AdsManagerApp.accountLabels().get();
  while (labelIterator.hasNext()) {
    var label = labelIterator.next();

    Logger.log('Label with id = %s and text = %s was found.',     label.getId().toFixed(0), label.getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in handling the MCC labels.

```
 AdsManagerApp.accounts().withCondition( 'LabelNames CONTAINS "test"' ).get();
```

And

```
  var accountIterator = AdsManagerApp.accounts().get();

  while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
      var account = accountIterator.next();
      var accountName = account.getName();

      var labelIterator = account.labels().get();
      while (labelIterator.hasNext()) {
          var label = labelIterator.next();
          var labelName = label.getName();

          if( labelName.match(/test/i) ) {
              Logger.log( accountName+" "+labelName );
          }
      }  
  }
```

WithCondition is not returning the user-level label names!